# UIWebView NSInvalidArgumentException When Playing Certain Video

Tags: ios, web, uiwebview, safari, avplayer

Create a UIWebView and load the following webpage:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.cbsnews.com/videos/asiana-crash-firefighters-focused-on-fire-not-what-was-outside-vehicle-safety-officer-says/"]];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.web loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Try playing the video then closing the video then playing it again. The second time you open the video the App crashes with the following exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An AVPlayerItem cannot be
>   associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer'

This looks like a bug with Apple's UIWebView class. I tried the same in Apple's safari but you can't play the video a second time in Safari for some reason (so they are avoiding the crash).

Any Ideas on how to fix this? I'm completely stuck.

Comment: "the second time you open the video", are you calling "`viewDidLoad`" a second time or are you opening the video a second time via a finger press within the web view?

Comment: Finger press within the web view.

Comment: We are also seeing this crash quite a lot. Any new info?

Comment: Unfortunately no new info. I believe this is just a bug with the way UIWebView handles video behind the scenes.